# Left-handers, Right-handers and Ambidexters problem in codeforces gives me an error

Tags: c++

when i submit it always give me wrong answer and i dont get where is the problem i succeed all 3 examples
https://codeforces.com/contest/950/problem/A

here is my code trying to solve the problem:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    int l, r, a, sum, total;
    cin >> l >> r >> a;
    sum = l + r;
    if (r == 0 && a == 0) {
        total = 0;
    }
    else if (l == 0 && a == 0) {
        total = 0; 
    }
    else if (sum % 2 == 0 && a % 2 == 0) {
        total = sum + a;
    }
    else if(sum % 2 == 0 && a % 2 != 0) {
        a--;
        total = sum + a;
    }
    else {
        sum--;
        total = sum + a;
    }
    cout << total;
}
```

Comment: Please also post the question or link to the question

Comment: Your code is over-complicated, try to think about a much simpler solution. Tip: first determine the maximum between lefties and rigthies.

Comment: Try the test case 1, 3, 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first find out the minimum of left and right, if 'a' is 0 this is the number a team can have, twice it, you get total players.

diff = max(l,r)-min(l,r)
if a >= diff, add a to minimum team to make both l == r and distribute the 'a' equally
else add 'a' to lesser team and that is the max you can have in the team.

in terms of code:

```
min = l < r ? l : r;
max = l > r ? l : r;

diff = max - min; 

if (diff == 0)  //both teams are equal from start
{
  min += a/2;
  max += a/2;
}
else
{
  if (a >= diff) 
  {
    min += diff
    /* now both teams are equal */
    a -= diff // only this much players are left in 'a'
    min += a/2;
    max += a/2; 
  }
  else
  {
     min += a;
  }
}

cout<<2*min<<"\n";
```